# Search Page: activate html code if the tag is on the page

Tags: pages, search, tags, conditional-tags

this is the first time that I write here and my English is not very good, I will try to explain as best as possible.

I want to activate some html text if in the result page, the results, has a particular tag.

For example: i have pages with the "locations" tag.

If I do a search, I wish in the search results, appears html code if the tag of the page reference is "locations". if the tags of the page is different, it should not appear nothing.

I'm looking for in the conditional tags, but I can not find anything like that.

I could express myself well?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, your question is clear!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is completely untested but I believe you would want something along these lines:

```
<?php 
if( $loop->have_posts() ):
  while ( $loop->have_posts() ): 
    $loop->the_post();
          // Do stuff for results
    echo '<h2>' . the_title() . '</h2>';

    // Check for tag
    if(has_tag($tag) { output HTML if true }

  endwhile;
else:
  echo "No Results!";
endif; 

?>
```